# Get selected file size using org.apache.cordova.file

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Using org.apache.cordova.file plugin I can selected the file and I get the native path of the file. After that I have to restrict the user to select the file according to there file size. But I can't get that **file size**. My problem is that I can't get the file Size using that plugin. For this I am using [this tutorial.](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/ionic-framework-cordova-and-file-api-a-media-player-app/)

Answer (score 6):

To get file size, you need to access it via metadata as follows:

```
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, 
                function (fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.getFile(fileName, {create: false}, 
                        function (fileEntry) {
                            fileEntry.getMetadata(
                                function (metadata) {
                                    alert(metadata.size); // get file size
                                }, 
                                function (error) {}
                            );
                        }, 
                        function (error) {}
                    );
                }, 
                function (error) {} 
            );
```

Comment: I am getting filePath undefined.. how to solve that?

Comment: I'm getting `error 5` on `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This code is a little more compact, as you don't need to call the getMetadata function, size is already a property of fileEntry

```
function gotPhoto(imageUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, 
        function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
                console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);
            },
            function (error) {});
        }, function (error) {}
    );
}
```

Comment: `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI` is deprecated, use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` instead

Answer (score 2):

The function `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI` is deprecated and furthermore you may need to have a specific dedicated transparent function for it.

Therefore you can declare this function.

```
function getFileSize(fileUri) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUri, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
                resolve(fileObj.size);
            },
            function(err){
                reject(err);
            });
        }, 
        function(err){
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

and then merely use it like this

```
getFileSize("myFileUri").
  then(function(fileSize){
     console.log(fileSize);
  }).
  catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  });
```