# How to check file size in angularJS without using directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I want to check file size using file path. I was successfully pick up files from camera/ image or photo viewer and file browser in my mobile application. And I got file and file full path also and I was successfully upload it onto server, but issue is that before uploading that file I want to check that file size. I search lot but I can't get proper solution. Every time I got the jQuery and angular directive is the solution. But I don't want to use both. **I want, when I pass the file path to the JS then it will be return file size.**

Comment: Did u use any plugin for upload your image from mobile to server ( cordova file api ) ?

Comment: Please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858805/get-selected-file-size-using-org-apache-cordova-file

Comment: Yes, $cordovaFileTransfer, for ref:- http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Answer (score 0):

```
function resolveLocalFileSuccessHandler(fileEntry) {
                alert(fileEntry.name);
                alert(fileEntry.fullPath);
                fileEntry.getMetadata(function(metadata) {
                    alert(metadata.size); // or do something more useful with it..
                });
            }
            function resolveLocalFileErrorHandler(error) {
                alert(error);
            }

            $window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, resolveLocalFileSuccessHandler, resolveLocalFileErrorHandler);
```